# Developing for BlackBerry with IntelliJ

Tags: unit-testing, blackberry, intellij-idea

I wonder if someone has idea about next.

I'm developing for BlackBerry. IDEA doesn't recognize RIM installation as JSDK or Mobile SDK. So I have create project without SDK and attach RIM jar file as dependency.

I'm trying to write as much as possible unit test with JUnit and Mockito but to run them IDEA requires JSDK. So I created additional module where I set JSDK, correct language level and it works. It's already hassle to create additional module (better if we could set JSDK and other compiler, runtime options for code and tests) but I was quite happy.

I have also dependencies for some common libraries which we use in android and J2ME also. I added them as modules with JSDK 1.6 and language level 1.3. And I able to develop and run test on it also.

But I got issue with LEDA EAP. IDEA now complaints about incompatibility with `java.lang` because it found them both in RIM jar and JSDK for libraries. And now I'm thinking about next hassle to fix my favorite ide. Sure it's EAP and things could be changed.

But anyone has any recommendation or similar situation setup?

Comment: I usually end up frustrated even with official BB SDK tools, so I think you are pushing BB development a step forward! XD

Comment: I agree that their tools require improvement